# Firebase on('child_added' is adding more unwanted childs / .once returns only the last one in the array

Tags: json, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, promise

Working on a node script to automatically call Google's pagespeed api upon giving the sites listed in a json file.

```
{
  "1" : "https://bitbucket.org",
  "2" : "https://www.catswhocode.com/blog/"
}
```

The aim is to add the results for the api call to firebase json database along with a top-level **url** node to store the firebase key for the sitestats entered. Here is example firebase data structure I need.

```
sites
 -KrehhWxld7XlKCuFSHRY
   stats { ... }
   url: "https://bitbucket.org"
 -KrehhXAWlYdjAOA9sd95
   stats { ... }
   url: "https://stackoverflow.com"
urls :
 393957be871e209a76e0dc5df1f526ec : -KrehhWxld7XlKCuFSHRY
 7f4c919540be6ec81cd37d9e61da6c37 : -KrehhXAWlYdjAOA9sd95
```

Within a promise I am adding a reference for the nodes in firebase json database.

```
Promise.all(allRes).then( function( values ) {
var ref = db.ref();
var sitesRef = ref.child("sites");
var urlsRef = ref.child("urls");
var psiresults = {};
  SitesArray.map(function (sites, index) {
    psiresults[sites] = values[index]
    desktopStats = values[index].desktopStats;
    mobileStats = values[index].mobileStats;
    sitesRef.push({
      url: sites,
      stats: metricsResponse
    });
    sitesRef.once('child_added', function(snapshot) {
      console.log(snapshot.key) //returns the last key only
    });
  });
```

When using `once('child_added', ...` it adds to the url top level node only for the very last item. However, if `on('child_added', ...` multiple copies of the same data and other childs are added. Not sure how to add the exact child key to the **urls** top level node when a child is added to **sites** node each time.

Comment: What is the `$uid` at `/urls/$uid/$pid`? Is is a `userId`?

Comment: You mean the md5 string 393957be871e209a76e0dc5df1f526ec? Used the site urls to create unique keys by hashing them using md5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I had to do it using..

```
sitesRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  ... 
});
```

This returns all the children and then I am able to filter the result based on my SitesArray values. I don't really find this an appropriate solution, however, I was able to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to process all URLs once, use `once('value'` with `snapshot.forEach()`:

```
sitesRef.once('value', function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
    console.log(child.key);
  });
});
```

Comment: If I do it with 'value' then I get all the values at once, I only want the new entries each time the script runs. However, 'child_added' only returns the last one.

Comment: There is no difference between `value` and `chid_added` for this. Each time the script runs, you will get triggered for all values. This is standard behavior for the Firebase Database. If you only want "new" values, you will have to come up with a definition of "new" (e.g. keep a property in each site to determine it has been processed already, or keep the push ID of the last site you've processed already).